# Txt file to arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I was wondering as I'm kinda new to python, how may I convert my txt file as :

```
-20.92060089 -27.72520065 -27.55229950 
-20.92469978 -27.69650078 -27.55340004 
-20.92469978 -27.69890022 -27.55170059
```

To arrays thats kind :

```
[[-20.92060089, -27.72520065, -27.55229950],
 [-20.92469978, -27.69650078, -27.55340004],
 [-20.92469978, -27.69890022, -27.55170059]]
```

Comment: Take a look at python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: The CSV module doesn't really help here, because it's not comma-separated value input.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson it's space separated. The delimiter can be configured.

Comment: @Wups it's still overkill for this minimal use-case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these lines can be split on " ", and you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) to grab this all at once.

I saved your text file as `/tmp/tfile.txt`, so then I can do this:

```
>>> array = [ line.split() for line in open("/tmp/tfile.txt").readlines() ]
>>> array
[['20.92060089', '-27.72520065', '-27.55229950'], ['-20.92469978', '-27.69650078', '-27.55340004'], ['-20.92469978', '-27.69890022', '-27.55170059']]
>>> len(array)
3
>>> array[0]
['20.92060089', '-27.72520065', '-27.55229950']
>>> array[1]
['-20.92469978', '-27.69650078', '-27.55340004']
>>> array[2]
['-20.92469978', '-27.69890022', '-27.55170059']
```

Comment: Ok thanks but we agree that I got string with this code ?

Comment: Sure - and if you want to make those into floats, do the conversion on each element of `line.split()`:

>>> array = [ [float(j) for j in line.split()] for line in open("/tmp/tfile.txt").readlines() ]

>>> array

[[20.92060089, -27.72520065, -27.5522995], [-20.92469978, -27.69650078, -27.55340004], [-20.92469978, -27.69890022, -27.55170059]]

>>> array[0][0]
20.92060089
>>> type(array[0][0])
<class 'float'>